# Disable removal of items

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using the mapping plugin to update a array from event sourcing events

```
this.itemMapping = {
    key: function (item) {
        return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.id);
    },
    create: function () {
        return new ItemViewModel();
    },
    update: function (options) {
        return options.target.update(options.data);            
    }
};
```

The problem is the events come in one at a time, but I want the array to reflect them all. Knockout mappings default behavior is to remove items not found in the data, can I disable this?

A fiddle showing the problem

http://jsfiddle.net/TJ3fv/

Comment: Short answer: No. You cannot disable it, you have write your own merging logic. The deleted items are not carried over to the `newContents` array  [see in source](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/blob/master/knockout.mapping.js#L623-L625). But you know this is open source so you just need to fork and fix it.

Comment: I checked the source, its too late in the delete case, the orginal item is deleted, so cant find its index etc to reinsert it. Tried to find a better place to intercept but the code is really hard to follow (The method updateViewmodel is a few hundret lines too long)

Comment: You can make it work on the dirty way... http://jsfiddle.net/MCs6f/

Comment: Does not work, the logic is heavily Dependant on comparing the new incoming array (Which misses the item)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. I found that much easier to create second observableArray and update it by subscribe.

```
function(){
    ko.mapping.fromJS({
        last_events: []     
    }, {}, this);

    events = ko.observableArray()

    this.last_events.subscribe(function(items){
        for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
            events.push(items[i])
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: How does this help? You will then have duplicates if same domain entity is updated twice. Your solution does not take merging into account